# store setting in relative path to executable aplication

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, settings

I am developing an application to run from USB, is it like a dock/launcher application but I have a problem.

I want to use My.Settings class to save my app settings, but it saves the setting file in AppData folder e.g. `C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Local\...\...\user.config`

I don't want that. I want to save in a path and name of my defined, e.g. `My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath` & `"\Settings.xml"`

How can I achieve this?

Update Example of final XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<conf>
    <pos>1</pos>
    <btn index="1" value="D:\League of Legends\" perm="true">LeagueClient.exe</btn>
    <btn index="2" value="D:\RuneLite\" perm="false">RuneLite.exe</btn>
    <btn index="3" value="" perm="false"></btn>
    <btn index="4" value="" perm="false"></btn>
</conf>
```

Full project in Github coming soon!!!

Comment: AFAIK you cannot change the path of the file generated from `My.Settings`, but you could instead create your own class to store the settings in and then use XML Serialization to write it to a file.

Comment: @VisualVincent have any example, of your code???

Comment: Unfortunately we don't do _examples_ on Stack Overflow. Lookup the subject instead, there are plenty of good articles out there. My personal favourite is this one: [Serialization 101 - Part III: XML Serialization](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/292726/Serialization-101-Part-III-XML-Serialization)

Comment: @VisualVincent not is vb.net

Comment: If you are referring to the article, it is infact for VB.NET too. If you look right after each C# example you'll see that there is a VB.NET version as well. But if you still aren't satisfied with the article, there are plenty more out there as I mentioned before. You can find one that is more for your liking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work way for me :

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Xml

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ValConfFile()
    End Sub
    Public Sub ValConfFile()
        If File.Exists("config.xml") = False Then : CreateConfXML() : End If
    End Sub
    Public Sub CreateConfXML()
        Dim obj As Object
        Dim archivo As Object
        Dim x As Integer = 1
        obj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        archivo = obj.CreateTextFile("config.xml", True)
        archivo.WriteLine("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>")
        archivo.WriteLine("<conf>")
        archivo.WriteLine("<pos>1</pos>")
        For x = 1 To 4
            archivo.WriteLine("<btn index='" & CStr(x) & "' value='' perm='false'></btn>")
        Next
        archivo.WriteLine("</conf>")
        archivo.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Whatever works for you of course, but I'd recommend actual serialization over simply writing/reading the XML yourself. By using serialization, a lot of error checking and structure verification is done for you, which improves the reliability of your code. Glad you managed to find a solution, though!

Comment: @VisualVincent Well for reasons of time I could not get to do the issue of serialization ... I am new to this and it would take me longer than this other solution that I found and only had to adapt ... and as nobody gave an answer to my question Only comments and opinions around ...

Comment: Just for the record, the reason I myself didn't write an answer was because without knowing your data structure, writing one would be unfitting for Stack Overflow as it would not be an _exact_ answer to your question. That's also the reason why we don't give mere examples: If you don't know for sure that it can answer the question, then it can't be considered an answer. For instance, you don't know if the example you are about to give is what the OP is actually looking for.

Comment: But _if_ you are still interested and would like to tell me what data you need to save and how you want/need to retrieve it, I can write up an answer for you using XML serialization.

Comment: I will update the question with the final XML that I want to obtain ... I will also be placing another question related to the same xml ... as you will see is an XML to save the button configurations programmatically ... and if the XML does not exist I must create an initial one ... practically when the program opens for the first time ... I will also be publishing the project github ... if you are interested in participating.

Comment: Hi again. I have provided an answer that suggests a solution using XML Serialization. Really sorry for taking so long to write it, this past week I've had some stuff that needed to be dealt with. If you have any questions just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

XML Serialization can be used for this, and is actually fairly straightforward. All you need to do is design one or more classes for your data, then apply the [appropriate attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization?view=netframework-4.8) (their name are in the form `Xml...Attribute`) in order to serialize them the way you want.

In this setup I've used four different attributes:

- `XmlElement` - Usually the most common one. Specifies that a property will be serialized as an element of its own. The resulting name can be customized by setting the `ElementName` parameter in the constructor.

  If used on lists or arrays, it applies to each item in the collection.
- `XmlRoot` - Pretty much the same as `XmlElement`, but used for the root element (the class itself).
- `XmlAttribute` - Specifies that a property will be serialized as an attribute (`name="value"`) applied to the parent object, instead of as an element inside it.
- `XmlText` - Specifies that a property's value will be serialized as the contents between the tags of the parent object (i.e. `<object>property value</object>`).

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Serialization

<XmlRoot(ElementName:="conf")>
Public Class Config

    <XmlElement(ElementName:="pos")>
    Public Property Position As Integer

    <XmlElement(ElementName:="btn")>
    Public Property Buttons As New List(Of ConfigButton)

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal Position As Integer)
        Me.Position = Position
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function Load(ByVal File As String) As Config
        Using FStream As New FileStream(File, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)
            Dim Serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(Config))
            Return Serializer.Deserialize(FStream)
        End Using
    End Function

    Public Sub Save(ByVal File As String)
        Using FStream As New FileStream(File, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)
            Dim Serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(Config))
            Serializer.Serialize(FStream)
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

```
Public Class ConfigButton

    <XmlText()>
    Public Property DisplayName As String

    <XmlAttribute("index")>
    Public Property Index As Integer

    <XmlAttribute("perm")>
    Public Property Perm As Boolean

    <XmlAttribute("value")>
    Public Property Value As String

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal DisplayName As String, ByVal Value As String, ByVal Index As Integer, ByVal Perm As Boolean)
        Me.DisplayName = DisplayName
        Me.Value = Value
        Me.Index = Index
        Me.Perm = Perm
    End Sub
End Class
```

Usage example:

```
Private cfg As Config

'
'Loading the config.
'

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handled MyBase.Load
    If File.Exists("config.xml") Then
        cfg = Config.Load("config.xml")
    Else
        cfg = New Config()
    End If
End Sub

'
'Saving the config.
'

Private Sub Form1_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
    cfg.Save("config.xml")
End Sub
```

Adding a button:

```
cfg.Buttons.Add(New ConfigButton("RuneLite.exe", "D:\RuneLite\", 2, False))
```

Iterating buttons:

```
For Each btn As ConfigButton In cfg.Buttons
    MessageBox.Show(btn.DisplayName)
Next
```

Removing a button at a specific index:

```
'Removes the fourth button.
cfg.Buttons.RemoveAt(3)
```